# why this view function is not free ether function?

Tags: view, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEMRK.png)

as you can see the image above, the function 'custLogIn' is view type (free on ether)
but after deploy the contract trhough Remix, it changed into non-free function.

I want to know about it and change into ether free function. please give your ideas. thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pure and view functions still cost gas if they are called internally from another function. They are only free if they are called externally, from outside of the blockchain.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/52887/60673) goes into greater depth on this topic.